# Fit IMG with a border inside a fixed-width DIV container

Tags: css, image, html, border

I have a fixed width `DIV` element. Inside of it, I have a second `DIV` which contains nothing but an `IMG` element. I would like to add a border to the image, without making it expand past the borders of either of the containing `DIV` tags.

**Attempt #1:**
If I try to add the border to the `IMG` directly, it expands past the fixed-width.
(see `image-container1`)

**Attempt #2:**
If I try to `box-sizing: border-box;` on the inner `DIV`, it cuts off the right-side of the image and shows a slight gap at the bottom of the image (between the border and image).
(see `image-container2`)

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/B2zQA/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- <br /> tags are used to show the container's width (green space) -->
    <br />
    <div id="image-container1"> <!-- Attempt #1 -->
        <img class="my-image1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Pardalotus_punctatus_female_with_nesting_material_-_Risdon_Brook.jpg/600px-Pardalotus_punctatus_female_with_nesting_material_-_Risdon_Brook.jpg" width="600" height="480" />
    </div>
    <br />    
    <div id="image-container2"> <!-- Attempt #2 -->
        <img class="my-image2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Pardalotus_punctatus_female_with_nesting_material_-_Risdon_Brook.jpg/600px-Pardalotus_punctatus_female_with_nesting_material_-_Risdon_Brook.jpg" width="600" height="480" />
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 500px;
}

#image-container1 {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#image-container1 img.my-image1 {
    border: red solid 30px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px red;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#image-container2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: red solid 30px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px red;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#image-container2 img.my-image2 {
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

How can I add a border to the image without having it expand past the edge of the fixed-width container? And it shouldn't have the right edge of the image cut-off either, or have a weird gap between the border and image.

Comment: add `display:block;` to `.my-image2` will fix the gap at its bottom

Comment: The images look distorted in the JSFIDDLE. I figured out it was because the HTML `IMG` tags were specifying a `width` and `height` but only the width was being scaled down correcntly in the CSS. I removed the w & h attributes from the HTML and the image then scaled properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Attempt #2" was very close to working...

- The gap below the image was solved by adding `display: block;` to the image directly, as suggested by @hmhcreative in his comment and answer
- The "right edge of the image cut-off" was my imagination (the picture didn't look centered) but I tried with an even BIGGER border and it became obvious that the image wasn't being cut-off

Here is the updated JSFIDDLE of my final solution: http://jsfiddle.net/B2zQA/2/

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following CSS for the second image in your markup:

```
#image-container2 {
    padding: 30px;
    background: red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px red;
}

#image-container2 img.my-image2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I had actually thought about this potential solution but I forgot to experiment with it; use a DIV with padding and a background-color. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: This didn't act great in my responsive layout. Sorry I didn't mention earlier that I am trying to make this work on various browser sizes. Your comment about using `display: block;` on the image helped me solve my problem though.